# JQuery Toggle only 1 item and the others not clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

Ok so i have this Jquery that will toggle some radio buttons on the page. I want it so when someone clicks on one of the radio buttons the others are not clicked. Currently the way i have it they can select 3 at a time and I need it to act like a regular radio button that one is clicked and the others are not

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
  $('.box-ul .btn .dot').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box-ul box-video right">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="yes"></span><p>Easy to Use</p></li>
        <li><span class="yes"></span><p>Step by Step<br /><span>details instructions</span></p></li>
        <li><span class="yes"></span><p>Setup time<br /><span>under 30 mins</span></p></li>
        <li class="btn btn-expanded">
          <div class="btn-t">
            <span class="dot left"></span>
          <p class="left">Expanded<br />
            <span>This is the extend button It has space for slightly more info.</span>
          </p>
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="btn">
          <div class="btn-t">
            <span class="dot left"></span>
            <p class="left">Green Doggies</p>
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
          </li>
        <li class="btn">
          <div class="btn-t">
            <span class="dot left"></span>
            <p class="left">Email Support</p>
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) class on all the matching elements that *aren't* the one you clicked on first, like this:

```
$('.box-ul .btn .dot').click(function () {
  $('.box-ul .btn .dot').not(this).removeClass('clicked');    
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});​
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/BsFe4/). In this case we're selecting all the other matching `'.box-ul .btn .dot'` elements, filtering out the one we clicked on with [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/), and doing a [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) on them.  The last part is still a [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) so you can de-select via clicking on the active one as well.  If you *don't* want to be able to de-select (even more like a radio button) then just change that to [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

Comment: @Matt - Welcome :) edited your question a bit...just for future reference, if you separate the JavaScript and HTML into different code blocks, you'll get better code highlighting on both :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a blanket .removeClass() on everything, I would do:

```
$(this).closest('.box-ul').find('.btn .dot').not(this).removeClass('clicked');
```

This only deselects ones within the clicked radio button's .box-ul.